# Generating CSS bundles with prefix names based on path with Vite

Tags: css, sass, components, config, vite

I'm upgrading a rather large project from Webpack to Vite. For this project I have a 'component' based project setup in which each component has their own directory. I'm using cssCodeSplit to render individual css and js files. I want the files to have a prefix based on what directory they originate.

Each component has a separate html(twig) and SCSS file like so:

```
components/
   button/
      button.twig
      button.scss
      button.js
   etc/
```

And i want the rendered CSS and JS file to be named `component-button.css` and `component-button.js`.

My current vite config uses the following method to get all component files as input:

```
const componentAssets = glob.sync('./components/**/{*,}/*.{js,scss}', { ignore: './**/_*.*' })  
  .reduce((acc, filePath) => {  
  const fileName = `component-${path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath))}`;  
  acc[fileName] = filePath;  
  return acc;  
  }, {});
```

This approach works for the js files, but this doesn't seem to work for the css bundles.

My rollupOptions are as follows:

```
rollupOptions: {  
   input: {  
     main: 'web/main.ts',  
      ...componentAssets,  
      <some other js and scss assets>
    }, output: {  
      assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[ext]',  
      entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',  
      chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',  
   },
 },
```

Is there a way i can make Vite use the 'component' prefix for these specified css files?

I've tried to use the `assetFileNames` to somehow deduce the path and extract the correct prefix but couldn't find a way to get this working.